# Comparing networks of groups of unequal size

Tags: time-series, sample-size, unbalanced-classes, networks, matching

I want to compare some network properties such as entropy, connectivity, etc., between 2 groups. I have time series fMRI data on patients (n = 80) and controls (n = 30) for certain regions of the brain.

My question is how should I correctly control for age and gender within my patient group before doing any further analyses? In addition to the unbalanced exposure groups, I have 3 times more females than males.  How can I best control for age and gender of the subjects?

Can I take 30 patients (randomly chosen if ties exist) whose means, variances / coefficients of variation match closely with those of the group overall, so that they represent the group well?

Comment: It isn't clear to me what is going on here. What do "networks" have to do w/ anything? Can you say more about your situation, your data, & your goals?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. My apologies for being unclear. I want to compare some network properties such as entropy, connectivity etc between 2 groups. I have time series fMRI data on patients and controls for certain regions of the brain. My question is how should I correctly control for age and gender within my patient group before doing any further analyses, as I have 80 patients as compared to 30 controls, with 3 times more females than males? Thanks in advance!